# PHP 301 Redirect a list of links

Tags: php, redirect

I have an interesting situation.  A site I was working on used to be in wordpress and there was a plugin called simple 301 redirects - what it did, was... create redirects for a list of pages that were hosted elsewhere...

**EXAMPLE**
If I typed in, "http://www.example.com/specificPage" - it would redirect me to a landing page at another location- "http://subdomain.example.com/specificPage".  I have a WHOLE list of these pages that need to have the redirect.

I know the basic one:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com/"); 
?>
```

How would that work for a big long list of say 35 of these "unique" links?  Would I have to create each of them and redirect them?  Or can i create just one page, maybe in connection with the HTACCESS file, and a simple code to do it for me?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Having a SEO-agency background i can say: Do it with 35 lines in .htaccess and you will be happy with that.

We have had htaccess files with far more than 2.000 301-redirects in it from time to time and there is nothing better.

Hope, this will help...

[EDIT] Some demo code

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^specificPage http://subdomain.example.com/specificPage [R=301,L, NC]
RewriteRule ^otherSpecificPage http://subdomain.example.com/otherSpecificPage [R=301,L, NC]
```

In some cases - depends on your specific webserver - you need to write with a ^/

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/specificPage http://subdomain.example.com/specificPage [R=301,L, NC]
RewriteRule ^/otherSpecificPage http://subdomain.example.com/otherSpecificPage [R=301,L, NC]
```

Comment: Do you think, taking @HenryTK's response and making each individual link would work?

Comment: Do you have an example of two or three that I can see - using the RewriteRule?

Comment: Cool! Let me try that!

Comment: Make sure, your webserver has an activated rewrite module, example in apache it would be mod_rewrite (in apache, see in conf/httpd.conf)

Comment: Would that be an apache handler?

Comment: It's an apache module, you have to activate ... the mod_rewrite is very often in the httpd.conf, but sometimes it is commented, so you have to remove the # right at the start of the line - and restart apache after that.

Comment: OK, I'm not finding it.  I'm on a godaddy shared hosting plan, and I don't know if I can access that sort of thing.

Comment: Okay, in this case, you should ask the support of your hoster what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a .htaccess file in the root directory of the old domain:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: will this handle ALL of the unique links without disrupting the other "natural" links on the site? Like example.com/about.php ?

Comment: I don't know the difference between unique link and natural link. It will take ANY path from the old domain and append it to the new domain. So `http://old-domain.com/folder/file.html` redirects to `http://new-domain.com/folder/file.html`

Answer (score 1):

OK! I figured it out!

using both of your responses, I was able to do this in my **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
Redirect 301 /specificPage http://subdomain.example.com/specificPage
```

And that worked nicely!
Thank you both, for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me, while the other two suggestions don't. You could mark it as the solution?!